# setting utf8 with mysql through php

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have the following very simple code, which retrieves utf8 formatetd data, such as containing umlauts from a mysql database, which may or may not be set as utf8. If I use either of the commented out approaches to ensure that utf8 data is returned, the data will NOT be returned as utf8, however if I leave them off, the data will be displayed. Why would forcing utf8 negate displaying data as utf8?

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "x", "", "x");
  //$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
  //$con-set_charset('utf8');
  $recordsQuery = "SELECT ARTICLE_NAME FROM AUCTIONS1";

  if ($getRecords = $con->prepare($recordsQuery)) {
        $getRecords->execute();
        $getRecords->bind_result($ARTICLE_NAME);

        while ($getRecords->fetch()) {
        echo "<p>$ARTICLE_NAME";
             }
    } else {
        print_r($con->error);
    }
```

Comment: if it's not returned in UTF-8, please show samples (including hex decodes if at all possible) of how it _is_ returned!

Comment: and also check that your tables are actually configured to use UTF-8 collation

Comment: the latter would be irrelevant .. the point of "SET NAMES" is exactly that MySql will convert if appropriate.

Comment: My tables are not set to use UTF-8 collation in this case, and so I though SET NAMES would ensure it was utf8. However, with SET NAMES enabled, it does not display as utf8. 

How can I show the differences in what is displayed?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the error lies in the charset you're serving the page with. If you're getting UTF-8 content out of the database and serving it with the default HTML charset of Windows-1252 then it's going to look garbled. Make sure you have the equivalent of this:

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

in your PHP code.

Comment: This is not in the test code I provided, but is set in my ajax application. The resulting page is definitely utf8, but if I set names utf8 the data displays garbled.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your data is already UTF-8 encoded in your database
2. configure database to deliver UTF-8 (eg. SET NAMES 'utf8')
3. use the right encoding on your website (nod to stak)

If you still have problems, please provide more data, especially what is *expected* and what finally *delivered*

Comment: It doesn't really matter what encoding is used to store the strings in the database, since most encodings (including the default iso-8859-1) can represent u-umlaut. MySql is charset aware, so it will convert to utf-8, if the connection is set to utf-8.