# Storing and displaying unicode string (हिन्दी) using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, internationalization

I have to store hindi text in a MySQL database, fetch it using a PHP script and display it on a webpage. I did the following:

I created a database and set its encoding to UTF-8 and also the collation to `utf8_bin`. 
I added a varchar field in the table and set it to accept UTF-8 text in the charset property.

Then I set about adding data to it. Here I had to copy data from an [existing site](http://www.mypanchang.com/2009/hi/Jammu-Kashmir-India/0/july.html).
The hindi text looks like this:  सूर्योदय:05:30

I directly copied this text into my database and used the PHP code `echo(utf8_encode($string))` to display the data. Upon doing so the browser showed me "??????".

When I inserted the UTF equivalent of the text by going to "view source" in the browser, however, सूर्योदय translates into `&#2360;&#2370;&#2352;&#2381;&#2351;&#2379;&#2342;&#2351;`.

If I enter and store `&#2360;&#2370;&#2352;&#2381;&#2351;&#2379;&#2342;&#2351;` in the database, it converts perfectly.

So what I want to know is how I can directly store सूर्योदय into my database and fetch it and display it in my webpage using PHP.

Also, can anyone help me understand if there's a script which when I type in सूर्योदय, gives me `&#2360;&#2370;&#2352;&#2381;&#2351;&#2379;&#2342;&#2351;`?

**Solution Found**

I wrote the following sample script which worked for me. Hope it helps someone else too

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hindi</title></head>
  <body>
    <?php
      include("connection.php"); //simple connection setting
      $result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); //the main trick
      $cmd = "select * from hindi";
      $result = mysql_query($cmd);
      while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result))
      {
          echo ($myrow[0]);
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The dump for my database storing hindi utf strings is

```
CREATE TABLE `hindi` (
  `data` varchar(1000) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin default NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `hindi` VALUES ('सूर्योदय');
```

Now my question is, how did it work without specifying "META" or header info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Did you set proper charset in the HTML Head section?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

or you can set content type in your php script using -

```
   header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

There are already some discussions here on StackOverflow - please have a look

[How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly/202246)
[setting utf8 with mysql through php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624301/setting-utf8-with-mysql-through-php)

[PHP/MySQL with encoding problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405684/php-mysql-with-encoding-problems)

> So what i want to know is how can i
>   directly store सूर्योदय into my
>   database and fetch it and display in
>   my webpage using PHP.

I am not sure what you mean by "directly storing in the database" .. did you mean entering data using PhpMyAdmin or any other similar tool? If yes, I have tried using PhpMyAdmin to input unicode data, so it has worked fine for me - You could try inputting data using phpmyadmin and retrieve it using a php script to confirm. If you need to submit data via a Php script just set the NAMES and CHARACTER SET when you create mysql connection, before execute insert queries, and when you select data. Have a look at the above posts to find the syntax. Hope it helps.

** UPDATE **
Just fixed some typos etc

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085093/strategy-for-supporting-unicode-multi-language-in-php5/

Comment: am not sure about that .. what was your character set earlier?

Comment: Better use mysql_set_charset() instead of 'SET NAMES', otherwise mysql_real_escape_string() isn't aware of the change. http://php.net/mysql_set_charset

Answer (score 24):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">


<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');

mysql_select_db('onlinetest',$con);

$nith = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TAMIL` (
  `data` varchar(1000) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin default NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

if (!mysql_query($nith,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

$nithi = "INSERT INTO `TAMIL` VALUES ('இந்தியா நாட்டின் பக்கங்கள்')";

if (!mysql_query($nithi,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");//the main trick
$cmd = "select * from TAMIL";
$result = mysql_query($cmd);
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo ($myrow[0]);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the code! I believe just `mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');` is enough for displaying the unicode characters?

Comment: How to display kannada font in mysql console my query "INSERT INTO lang values ('ಕನ್ನಡ ಸತ್ಯ ಕನ್ನಡ ನಿತ್ಯ')";

Answer (score 9):

For those who are looking for PHP ( >5.3.5 ) PDO statement, we can set charset as per below:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
```

Comment: this works for me, also dont forget to add        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> in your head section

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE DATABASE hindi_test
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
USE hindi_test;
CREATE TABLE `hindi` (`data` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
INSERT INTO `hindi` (`data`) VALUES('कंप्यूटर');
```

Answer (score 2):

For Those who are facing difficulty just got to php admin and change collation to **utf8_general_ci**
Select Table go to Operations>> table options>> collations should be there