# Why am I returning empty records when querying in mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql

**I created the following script to query a table and return the first 30 results.  The query returns 30 results, but they do not have any text or information.  Why would this be?**

The table stores Vietnamese characters. The database is mysql4.

Here's the page: http://saomaidanang.com/recentposts.php

Here's the code:

```
<?php
  header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
 //CONNECTION INFO
 $dbms = 'mysql'; 
 $dbhost = 'xxxxx';
 $dbname = 'xxxxxxx';
 $dbuser = 'xxxxxxx';
 $dbpasswd = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';    
 $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd ) or die('Error connecting to mysql');
 mysql_select_db($dbname , $conn);

 //QUERY
 $result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
 $cmd = 'SELECT * FROM `phpbb_posts_text` ORDER BY `phpbb_posts_text`.`post_subject` DESC LIMIT 0, 30 '; 
 $result = mysql_query($cmd);
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>recent posts</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <p>

<?php 
 //DISPLAY
 while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result))
 {
  echo 'post subject:';
  echo(utf8_encode($myrow ['post_subject']));
  echo 'post text:';
  echo(utf8_encode($myrow ['post_text']));
 }
?>
 </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you use utf8_encode? it seems quite unnecessary

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Because I have no idea what I'm doing?

Seriously, I'm using it because of this stackoverflow question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701  He had a similar issue and utf8_encode solved it.

Comment: As I can see he said SET NAMES utf8 did the trick.
Try your code without utf8_encode, it should work fine.
You have set everything right and no additional recode needed.

Comment: Also, thanks to @Col. Shrapnel for telling me to remove utf8_encode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

- The former returns an array with each
  result column stored in an array
  offset, starting at offset 0.
- The later returns an associative
  array of strings where the column as
  used as keys.

And in your program you are using the result as an associative array:

```
$myrow ['post_subject']
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I will try this tonight when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

or you could try `mysql_fetch_object()` and access the data as `$myrow->post_subject`. If you feel the data is still not displayed, then do a `print_r($myrow)` to the the output. This way you will know for sure if the data has been returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you use mysql_fetch_row(), you're going to need to access your data through numbered keys (ie $row[0], $row[1], etc). mysql_fetch_object() is the norm today in most applications to fetching rows as mentioned by Shamly.

I'm not a big fan of using PHP's provided functions to do daily coding. Instead, considering writing (or downloading) a class or a few functions to help do the job for you, like:

```
function my_query($query){
  $return = array(); // stuff to return

  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    array_push($return, $row);
  }

  return $return;
}
```

So then all you have to do is this in your script:

```
// connect to db, fill in the appropriate arguments...
$link = mysql_connect(...);

// selecting database
mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);

// do the query
$rows = my_query(...);
foreach($rows as $row){
   print_r($row); // see what's in there...
}
```

By using the my_query() function, you save yourself a few steps. This is also particularly useful doing nested queries within loops. What's easier to read?

```
// assume database is already connected
$result = mysql_query('SELECT user_id FROM table');
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
   $result_2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM other_table WHERE user_id = '.$row->user_id);
   while($row_2 = mysql_fetch_object($result_2)){
       // do stuff with both rows
       // potential for lots of confusion and mysql errors
   }
}
```

or this...

```
// assume database is already connected
$user_ids = my_query('SELECT user_id FROM table');
foreach($user_ids as $x){
    $more_data = my_query('SELECT * FROM other_table WHERE user_id = '.$x->user_id);
    foreach($more_data as $y){
        // do stuff 
    }
}
```

Anyway, probably a much longer answered than you expected, but I hope it gives you an idea of how to go about things :) If you have time, install Wordpress and learn how to use its built in $wpdb object. You will gain a wealth of knowledge of how databases are used in real life applications and you'll be able to make your own database class to suit your needs.

DISCLAIMER: I just wrote all the above code for this post without testing for syntax errors. I apologize if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ ... }
```

it will work