# PHP curl hit special characters

Tags: php

The API response is displaying special characters instead of actual words (the actual words are from the tamil language)

What header should I add in this? Please provide some example.

Getting special like below:

```
à®•à®¿à®´à®®à¯ˆ
```

Function

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: finally i fixed with below thread 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701/storing-and-displaying-unicode-string-using-php-and-mysql][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701/storing-and-displaying-unicode-string-using-php-and-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use Tamil charset. Check out the following link:

http://www.iam.uni-bonn.de/~alt/html/unicode_25.html

Use header like this:

```
$headers = array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset: UTF-8");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your sugesstion, i have tried given snippet, but it is not worked as i expected, as well u have provided reference URL, i dont know how to apply that url mentioned 0B80 this code in CURL. please advise on this.

Comment: Try to use `charset: 0B80` in the above snippet.

Comment: $headers = array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset:0B80");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);  not worked, still same special characters