# How to view hindi font on Browser in json format

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to display text in **Hindi** for that I change Collation to **`utf8_general_ci`** in MySQL but when I try to view data in JSON format using PHP it's showing **`???`** instead of **`नकद`**. 
Here is my web service:

```
    <?php
        require_once 'include/DB_Config.php';

// Create connection
$conn =new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);    

if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM receipt";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);


 }

} else {
 echo "0 results";
}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

Try to use `echo json_encode($tem, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`
 
what can I do to  display hindi font in Browser from php.

Comment: possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701/storing-and-displaying-unicode-string-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%80-using-php-and-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing and displaying unicode string (हिन्दी) using PHP and MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701/storing-and-displaying-unicode-string-%e0%a4%b9%e0%a4%bf%e0%a4%a8%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%a6%e0%a5%80-using-php-and-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the charset after creating the connection

```
$conn =new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```

more details on http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.set-charset.php

otherwise it's likely still latin depending on your php instalation