# How to make laravel read foreign language characters from mysql database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

It is converting a readable character to "á‹á‹µ á‹°áŠ•á‰ áŠ›". I am using "utf-8" for the columns of the table

Comment: make sure in your database config file you have `'charset' => 'utf8mb4', 'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',` these.

Comment: Did you try Database charset `utf8` and Database collation `utf8_general_ci` ?

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara and Harun I tried those, it didn't work

Comment: You can try following question feedback [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701/storing-and-displaying-unicode-string-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%80-using-php-and-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure as the comments said the database character is set to be  utf8mb4_unicode_ci or utf8_general_ci the first charset is for the emojis anyway back to the issue  .. make sure that the php files is set to be utf8 too .. by using a modern editor like phpstorm or vscode or sublime .. you might try to use tinker .. by typing `php artisan tinker` in your terminal window or command line if you're using widows -> then try to add a record in your database with the non-english language then check it again .. if it doesn't convert to this gibberish so the the problem is not with the database charset is with files as I said.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that your .env file has the following attributes:

```
DB_CHARSET=utf8
DB_COLLATION=utf8
```

It will force laravel to use this charset and collation on all queries it runs.