# MySQL - insert japanese from PHP - Encoding Troubles

Tags: php, mysql, database, unicode, encoding

I'm trying to insert some japanese words in a mysql table!
If I insert 'こんにちは' using phpMyAdmin, the word is displayed fine from phpMyAdmin.
But if I try to insert it through php, as follow:

```
mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
mysql_select_db($Database);

$qry = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (0 , 'こんにちは')";

echo mysql_query($qry);
```

In phpMyAdmin i see "ã“ã‚“ã«ã¡ã¯" ... why?

And if I try to fetch from the database:

```
$arr = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table where id = 1"));

echo $arr[1];
```

The browser shows nothing!!!

How can I solve?

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

---

**~EDIT~**

My database collation is setup to utf8_general_ci

---

**~EDIT 2~**

I don't need to display the output on an HTML page, but the japanese words are printed on a XML page whose encoding is setup to UTF-8.

```
$plist = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
$plist .= "<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">\n";
$plist .= "<plist version=\"1.0\">\n";
$plist .= "<array>\n";
$plist .= "\t<dict>\n";
$plist .= "\t\t<key>test</key>\n";
$plist .= "\t\t<string>".$arr[1]."</string>\n";
$plist .= "\t</dict>\n";
$plist .= "</array>\n";
$plist .= "</plist>";

echo $plist;
```

the output of this code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>test</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

So, there is no value for the key "test" ... what can I do? Thanks!

---

**~ SOLVED ~**

Problems solved using the function mysql_set_charset() after connecting to the database!

Comment: For this (Mojibake) and other utf8 problems see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this before the insert query

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Also not sure if you set the proper charset of the database, and of the web page.

Charset in HTML Head section?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

and/or something like

```
   header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

Followings will help you get more ideas how to do it .. if something doesnt work commment back.

check more here on SO

[Storing and displaying unicode string (हिन्दी) using PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701/storing-and-displaying-unicode-string-using-php-and-mysql/1198713#1198713)

[How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly/202246)

[setting utf8 with mysql through php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624301/setting-utf8-with-mysql-through-php)

[PHP/MySQL with encoding problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405684/php-mysql-with-encoding-problems)

Comment: Thank you!
the command mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); solves my problem about insert japanese words in the database!
But the problem on displaying these words on the XML is not fixed!

Comment: Did you set encoding there in XML?

Comment: Yes, you can see the XML code in the second EDIT section of my post!

Answer (score 0):

you must set you Database Charset to utf8 and database collation to utf8_general_ci (or other utf8 collation)  then I think your problem solved